# How can i show the series of numbers in one dialog?

Tags: java, fibonacci, joptionpane

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

public class FibonacciSeries {
public static void main(String[] args){

```
    String userInput;

    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 0, d = 0;

    userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a number of series", "Fibonacci Series", -1);
    int fn = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

    for (d = 0 ; d < fn; d++)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fibonacci Series: "+ a,"Fibonacci Series", -1);
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;

    }
}
```

}

i need to print the series of number example : 1 1 2 3 5 in one dialog i dont know how

Comment: I just started learning java in our university

Comment: Have a `String output` that you add `c` to (e.g. `output = output + c + " "`) until the loop is finished and only then display a single dialog showing that string. Alternatively use a list that you join in the end or use a StringBuilder, etc.

Comment: ... and your dialog needs to be called *after* the loop

Comment: [Flowchart](https://ibb.co/V9ZdKhZ) this is what i need to follow for coding, but the problem is just the dialog